# Finger controlled view slide animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I would like to know how to implement an animation where the user can slide one view over another using his finger. To simplify things I will post some pictures to explain what I mean.

At first we have a view which has a settings icon (that pink thingie in the upper left corner). The view can can be manipulated by any means necessary - including swiping. See picture 1.
[image: picture 1]

When the user presses the settings button the view slides away and reveals settings view underneath. To do this I just use `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]` adjust the main view `frame` and commit animations. The situation looks like this: (settings are purple, main view is still the same colour)

[image: picture2]

Now when the user decides he want the main screen back he will have to grab it and slide it back into its place. HOW? Now I have been using `UITapGestureRecognizer` which would trigger a reverse animation so that the view slid back in its original place. That was messy and the user was still able to manipulate that small section of the view visible.

I want the view to follow the user's finger and slide and scale its way back in its place. The main view should not be manipulatable while moving. To understand what I mean you can check the Yahoo Weather app which has a similar thing going on - except that my view would also shrink a bit vertically. The third picture shows things "in motion":

[image: picture3]

Please provide links or code that can help me accomplish this.
Cheers, Jan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code:

1. [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)
2. [MSMatrixController](https://github.com/MarcoSero/MSMatrixController)

And you can try this

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint touchPt = [touch locationInView:self];

    float deltaX = touchPt.x - beginPt.x; //where beginPt is CGPoint variable which was set in touches began
    float deltaY = touchPt.y - beginPt.y;
    if (deltaX < 0) {
        deltaX = -deltaX;
    }
    if (deltaY < 0) {
        deltaY = -deltaY;
    }

    CGPoint toPt;
    toPt.x = deltaX;
    toPt.y = deltaY;

    yourMovedView.center = toPt;
}
```